# HTTP to HTTPS through catalogue doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my `.htaccess`.

I am forwarding from `HTTP` to `HTTPs` in my `.htaccess` file, without `WWW`, but I keep getting an error (only shows a white page).

Below you can see my current (working) `.htaccess` with `HTTP`. Can anyone give me a tip how to change this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?new\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?server1660223\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain/$1 [L]

<Files xmlrpc\.php>
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This will remove `www` from your URLs and then force `HTTPs` as well. Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.